# My code is throwing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Matching real methods not found for the following mocks error

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

what am i doing wrong in the below code?could someone suggest something.

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
class testingClassTest {

//Added annotations on the classes

    @InjectMocks
    private TestingClass testClassObj;
    @Mock
     DO dO;
     private Exception ex;

    @Before
     public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        dO = new DO();
     }


//method to be tested

    @Test
    void testProcess() {
       dO = new dO();
        ex = new MyException(new ArrayList<>(),null);
        new MockUp<Mockingclass>() {
            @mockit.Mock
            public void method(Object obj, String st, Exception ex, String msg, ObjectConfig obj) {
                dO.setCd(Interfacecontaingconst.CD);
            }
        };
        testObj.method(DO,"6",ex,null, null);
        Assert.assertEquals(139,dO.getCd());
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using both JMockit and Mockito which probably isn’t helping. It also looks like you are getting Mockito to create a mock `DO` and then replacing that with an instance you have created yourself. It’s not clear to me exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson Thanks for your response. I’m also confused slightly. I created an instance of Do because do.method call throw null pointer exception. It say find why do could be null.